# How do I find the duplicate ID in a table when doing INSERT IGNORE?

Tags: php, mysql

I know that when doing a `INSERT IGNORE` duplicate entries are ignored and errors become warning but here is what I need.

Scenario: We have a table with 2 columns `(id, name)` where BOTH are `UNIQUE` and `id` is `PRIMARY KEY`.

When you do an `INSERT IGNORE` on column `name` it creates the next `AUTO_INCREMENT` for `id` (even though it later doesnt exist in your DB, its just skipped) and when you call `LAST_INSERT_ID` it gives you the that next `id`. However I need to find the `id` that caused the query to be ignore. In other words the `id` of the `name` that was a duplicate.

Any MySQL/PHP trick is welcomed. :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can extract this information with INSERT IGNORE. Even if the warning text would contain the key value, there are only so many warnings buffered, so you couldn't rely on that.

I would probably try to rewrite the query so that it avoids inserting a duplicate. You can always detect the keys before hand by doing a

```
SELECT id FROM tab WHERE name in ('...value1...',...,'...valueN...')
```

Depending on the format of the data you want to insert, and how you are doing the inserts (bulk, or one row at a time) you can do several things to avoid inserting known duplicates.

If on the other hand you had the idea of extracting the IDs of the would-be duplicates to perform an update for those rows instead, then you should use the `REPLACE` syntax (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replace.html) or the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` construct (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: That was the initial idea but I was trying to keep my queries to a minimum. After a couple more hours of research I gave up and decided to just clean my insert data of duplicate entries and the insert it. Thanks for you help.